# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Sticky Footer not working on IE11 and IE Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky-footer

It works on chrome but not on IE. I really need your help.

The site I am working is:

http://www.westerncircuit.com/results.php

I am trying to get sticky footer to work on IE but I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code.

I had tried including:

1. ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js
2. ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css

But it didn't worked. I have all the files required for the sticker footer such as bootstrap css, js and sticky-footer css. I really have no idea what am I missing.

Your kind assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: I see problems in Firefox, inspect element tool is not even able to load css

Comment: I have not tried using Firefox, I will check it out later, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just need to add

> navbar-fixed-bottom

to my footer for it to work.